# Revert decoded html string back to encoded string wihout losing tags

Tags: java, android

I wanna convert a decoded html CharSequence back to normal form. I can't find a way to do it. In my example, after converting it back, I got only "text" in both variable b and c. It should include bold tag.

```
CharSequence a = Html.fromHtml("<b>text</b>");
String b = Html.escapeHtml(a);
// b is now "text", cannot convert back to "<b>text</b>"
String c = TextUtils.htmlEncode(a);
// same as b
```

By the way, I need to use only CharSequence for decoded html. No String. For encoded html, any type is ok.